# Blender communication with SuperCollider via OSC

Tags: python

Halo to everyone,

I need help with OSC output.

Three years ago I used movements in Blender to control some variables in the [SuperCollider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperCollider). Now with the new versions of Blender and SuperCollider it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Edit your original question, give more information (scripts etc). Any scripts that once worked with older version of blender can most likely be made to work with the latest blender API.